# Using remote config from firebase to change URL of videoView

Tags: android

What I need is: Change the URL of the video view whenever I change the remote config parameters!

I'm making a tv channel app using video view.
   to show the TV channels if the format of the url .m3u8 is used, but this link changes daily so IMPOSSIVEL I stay updating my application every day that change this link .... so I discovered (actually I remembered) that in firebase there is a option "remote config" that it is possible to change these links ...
   
  What do I want anyway? How can I do this by using the remote config

```
package tk.protvapp.protv;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class FoxActivity extends Activity {
    VideoView myVideoView;
    View v;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fox);

        myVideoView = (VideoView)this.findViewById(R.id.videofox1); MediaController mc = new MediaController(this); myVideoView.setMediaController(mc);
        final String urlStream = "//Search the link in remote config for paste here";
        myVideoView.start();
        myVideoView.findFocus();
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { @Override public void run() { myVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(urlStream)); } });
    }
    public void voltarhomefox(View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent(FoxActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

### My layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000"
    tools:context="tk.protvapp.protv.FoxActivity">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="voltarhomefox"
        android:text="VOLTAR" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout">

        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/videofox1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: the application alone will look in the remote config the video view link

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you're asking.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm using google translate

Comment: I want that, the application proure in the remote config of the firebase the Link of the Video view

Comment: Whenever this activity is opened, the video view looks for this parameter:
https://i.imgur.com/uwv6YN7.png

So .... if I change the value of the parameter, when the application looks again the link (in the parameter) will change to the new) :)